# kotlin coroutines, how does launch handles exception

Tags: exception, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

with

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
runBlocking {

        withTimeout(1300L) {
            repeat(1000) { i ->
                    println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
                delay(500L)
            }
        }

}
}
```

it crashes with exception:

```
I'm sleeping 0 ...
I'm sleeping 1 ...
I'm sleeping 2 ...
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 1300 ms
 at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutKt.TimeoutCancellationException (Timeout.kt:128) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCoroutine.run (Timeout.kt:94) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase$DelayedRunnableTask.run (EventLoop.kt:307) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent (EventLoop.kt:116) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor.run (DefaultExecutor.kt:68) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

but with the block inside a `launch`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
runBlocking {
    launch {//<===
        withTimeout(1300L) {
            repeat(1000) { i ->
                    println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
                delay(500L)
            }
        }
    }//<===
}
}
```

then there is not exception of the timeout:

```
I'm sleeping 0 ...
I'm sleeping 1 ...
I'm sleeping 2 ...
```

why there is no exception with launch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TimeoutCancellationException` is a sub-class of `CancellationException`.
CancellationExceptions that are thrown inside a Coroutine that was `launch`ed do not propogate to any exception-handler, not to a CoroutineExceptionHandler and not to the Thread's Uncaught Exception Handler (the last one was called in your first example).

Here is a modified version of your 2nd example, where the CancellationException is wrapped in a plain RuntimeException (something that is not a CancellationException). You'll see the stacktrace log again:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runBlocking {
        launch {
            try {
                withTimeout(1300L) {
                    repeat(1000) { i ->
                        println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
                        delay(500L)
                    }
                }
            } catch (t: CancellationException) { 
                throw RuntimeException(t)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main thing why launch and runBlocking work differently is because runBlocking it should return value, but because scope is cancelled, nothing to return and it throws cancellation exception, for launch it just cancel coroutine

Here you can find more about coroutines and exceptions:
https://link.medium.com/HEhVwUxOkY

Answer (score 0):

> Cancellation is closely related to exceptions. Coroutines internally
> use `CancellationException` for cancellation, these exceptions are
> ignored by all handlers, so they should be used only as the source of
> additional debug information, which can be obtained by catch block.
>
> Source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#cancellation-and-exceptions

`launch` builder ignores `TimeoutCancellationException`

> The `TimeoutCancellationException` that is thrown by `withTimeout` is a
> subclass of `CancellationException`. We have not seen its stack trace
> printed on the console before. That is because inside a cancelled
> coroutine `CancellationException` is considered to be a normal reason
> for coroutine completion. However, in this example we have used
> `withTimeout` right inside the main function.
>
> Source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#timeout